# Getting Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, mismatch

It's working fine at local system but when hosting it on server, it's giving error. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Dim ForumID As String = Session("ForumID").ToString()
    Dim cforumId As Int32 
    cforumId = Convert.ToInt32(ForumID)
    Dim userId As String = User.Identity.Name.ToString()
    Dim Comments As String = (TextBox3.Text).ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br />")       
    DIm PostedTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("f")
    Dim sqlcmd As OleDbCommand

    connection.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("Database.mdb"))
    connection.Open()
```

I'm using access as Database. Forum column is reference key to another table and is interger (Number) datatype. Rest are text datatype.

```
    sqlcmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into Thread (ForumID, Comments, UserID, PostedTime) values('@cforumId','@Comments','@userId','@PostedTime')", connection)

    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
    TextBox3.Text = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to do the right thing and use parameters but you're making a mess of it.  That code is literally going to try to insert the text values "@cforumId", "@Comments", "@userId" and "@PostedTime" into the ForumID, Comments, UserID and PostedTime columns respectively.  What you need to do is make those things in the `VALUES` clause parameter place-holders rather than strings and then add the appropriate parameters, e.g.

```
sqlcmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Thread (ForumID, Comments, UserID, PostedTime) VALUES ('@ForumID','@Comments','@UserID','@PostedTime')", connection)

With sqlcomd.Parameters
    .AddWithValue("@ForumID", forumId)
    .AddWithValue("@Comments", comments)
    .AddWithValue("@UserID", userId)
    .Add("@PostedTime", OleDbType.Date).Value = postedTime
End With

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Note that the way the last parameter is added and set is different because, in the default case, `AddWithValue` will infer the wrong data type for a `DateTime` value.  If `AddWithValue` works for you then go with it.